# "Unknown Error" in Microsoft Graph API Get Staff Availability in MS Bookings

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api, microsoft-graph-booking, graph-explorer

When trying to make a request to the graph API endpoint for getting staff availability info on MS Bookings I keep receiving the below error which returns status code 500. I had followed the guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/bookingbusiness-getstaffavailability?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) and also decoded my access token and verified I had the right permissions.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownError",
        "message": "",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2022-07-25T08:21:46",
            "request-id": "aa302590-9a6e-47a4-a5ac-51a12ef5e72e",
            "client-request-id": "aa302590-9a6e-47a4-a5ac-51a12ef5e72e"
        }
    }
}
```

I also encountered the same error in graph explorer.

Comment: I encountered the same problem, and made a github post about it:

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-explorer-v4/issues/2043

Answer (score 1):

Well this seemed to work for me when I changed the timeZone value on the request payload from my local time zone to 'UTC'. So my request payload was changed as below
[image]

However same error persists on graph explorer - guessing its because application permissions are not currently supported on graph explorer